# How can i show my phyton's desktop projects in my portfolio?

Tags: python, desktop-application

I'm almost finishing my portfolio and i put some links of my web apps in javascript in the portfolio to show my works, but my projects in python are all desktops app, so i don't know how to put my python projects alongside my javascript web projects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix to the problem, use a service like replit to host your code in cloud, replit allows you to share your Python, Java, C# etc code with a terminal so that viewers can run it. Here is an example of a replit that uses python [Replit](https://replit.com/@omg32/Console-Games?v=1)

Comment: thank you very much. It looks interesting that page.